# Run my code written in Scala IDE (eclipse) in REPL

Tags: eclipse, scala, apache-spark

I have written my Spark code in Scala IDE (eclipse) and it 'runs' well here.(it is a Scala object and I have saved it as a .scala file on my computer)
Now i'm trying to run it in REPL. I'm not sure how I can run it in REPL, by copy-pasting it or by 'loading'.
[Run in Scala IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6nMj.png),

[Run in REPL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0f1G1.png)

Any help in this case would be greatly appreciated.
regards,
Behrouz

Comment: `:load file.scala`

Answer (score 1):

There are two option you can `load` a file and `paste` the content.

To `load` a file use

```
:load filename.scala
```

To paste the content

```
:paste Command-V on a Mac, Ctrl-V on Windows)
```

and press `CTRL-D` for evaluate